# Помогите понять, как представляется объект в памяти в C#?

Tags: c#

Например, у меня есть базовый класс А и наследующийся от него класс B.

```
A objA = new B();
```

Создав объект objA, какого же все-таки типа я получаю объект?
Хранятся ли где-то в памяти указатели на все родительские классы?

Comment: так как вызывается _new B_ - объект типа `B`

Comment: Это путаница из-за отсутствия указателей и стрелочек привычных в С++. На самом деле в С# все указатели. на С++ ваша строчка имела вид A *objA = new B(); И вы бы спокойно ее восприняли с учетом полиморфизма. Создали объект В и присвоили указателю типа А, и благодаря полиморфизму все работает. В C# по привычки читается как будто у вас объявлен объект А, и вы ему присвоили объект B. Но на самом деле это все ссылки. Без начального присвоения А не существует и пользоваться им нельзя.

Comment: @AndreyGolikov - точно - все дело в том, что стрелочек не хватает

Comment: @AndreyGolikov в C# есть указатели, прям как в C++, даже с арифметикой. Другое дело, что здесь new возвращяет **ссылки**, которые ведут себя иначе, чем как в С++.

Comment: Да не корректно выразился. Указатели как указатели - это небезопасная часть шарпа, я бы сказал это скорее исключение. И определение ссылки подходил лучше, вы правы.

Comment: Стрелочки нужны тем, кто пришёл из C. В других языках (JS, Python, например) ссылочные объекты имеют синтаксис с точкой, и это не вызывает удивления.

Answer (score 4):

С оговоркой на текущую реализацию CLR и предполагая что под классом вы подразумевали именно класс:

После выполнения вашего кода вы получите:

- Экземпляр класса B, лежащий в куче.
- Адрес этого экземпляра, лежащий в локальной переменной objA.

Внутри экзепляра класса лежит системное поле TypeHandle, которое указывает на таблицу методов (MethodTable) типа (класса B), которому принаджежит экземпляр.

Внутри MethodTable есть ссылка на метаданные о собственно типе B (полях, свойствах, методах и прочем) - EEClass.

В EEClass класса B есть ссылка на EEClass родительского типа - класса A.

В целом получается примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка взята из [MSDN: Внутреннее устройство .NET Framework — как CLR создает объекты периода выполнения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335945.05(l=ru-ru).jpg) - статья чуть битая, картинки подгружаются по клику.

Comment: А почему никто не плюсует?

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас `A` и `B` — классы (то есть, ссылочные типы), следует различать между compile-time (заявленным) типом ссылки и runtime- (фактическим) типом.

Заявленный тип — `A`, и на этапе компиляции вы по этой ссылке можете пользоваться лишь операциями, доступными в классе `A`. А фактический тип — `B` (и это легко проверить, определив виртуальную функцию в `A` и перекрыв её в `B`).

Ссылка в C# может ссылаться на любой объект типа, *совместимого по присваиванию* с типом ссылки. Например, если `A` — класс, то объект производного типа. Если `A` — интерфейс, то объект типа, имплементирующего интерфейс. (Интерфейсы в C# не являются классами.) Если `A = object`, то (упакованные) типы-значения наподобие `int`.

---

Как именно хранятся в памяти объекты, вам не должно быть интересно: это не оговаривается стандартом (как и само *наличие* стека и кучи, например). Вам должны быть важны только семантика *присваивания* и *тождества*: если вы присваиваете одной ссылке другую, они ссылаются на один и тот же объект, и изменения в этом объекте видны по обеим ссылкам. Тождественными считаются ссылки, ссылающиеся на один и тот же объект (для проверки нужно использовать `object.ReferenceEquals`).

---

А если `А` — структура (то есть, тип-значение), то от неё вовсе нельзя наследоваться. Для структур при присваивании вы получаете *копию* структуры, и изменения в одной не влияют на изменения в другой. Тождественными считаются структуры с одинаковыми полями. Разные два экземпляра такой структуры не отличимы (так же как вы не отличаете два «экземпляра» числа 5, например).

Answer (score 0):

Если A - **reference type**, то вы получаете ссылку, которая ссылается на некоторый объект в хипе. Объект этот имеет тип B, с ним лежит ссылка на объект его типа (который тоже где-то в хипе).
Если A - **value type**, то вы получаете ссылку objA на объект в стеке.

У [Рихтера в "CLR via C#"](http://sd.blackball.lv/library/CLR_via_CSharp_(Jeffrey_Richter_4th_Edition).pdf) об этом хорошо описано. "Chapter 4 Type Fundamentals, How Things Relate at Runtime ", стр. 105

Comment: Не обязательно в хипе. Это подробность поведения текущей версии CLR (в будущем или на Mono имеет право быть на так).

Comment: для value type не будет никакой ссылки на объект objA в стеке. Будет просто объект в стеке, в том куске его, который выделен под локальную переменную objA.